# Macro variable to SAS date

Tags: date, sas, sas-macro

quick question here.

How could I adapt this code so that it would work with  `%let DTD=2012-12-31;`

```
%let DTD=31-DEC-2013;

DATA _Null_;
dd="&DTD"d;
put dd;
RUN;
```

Then dd has a value of 19723.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to use INPUT instead of "&var"d;

```
dd = input("&DTD",yymmdd10.);
```

Now, hopefully you wouldn't use 2012-12-32, since that's not a real date.  :)